# IntelliJ find SSH Password

Tags: linux, ssh, jetbrains-ide

Basically, I'm an idiot who decided to accidentally remove my password from my list (I use randomly generated passwords so I can't remember it and I was in the middle of changing my password). I'm used to Linux just letting you do it whenever you are in root, so I didn't think it was an issue. But you do need to know your old password to switch.

Now, here's the situation: I do still have the password cached in IntelliJ's SSH feature. However, I don't know where it's stored locally to obtain it, (if it's even stored locally).

I can't get into root on this system, and sudo is unavailable.
Is there any way to retrieve this password?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reference-ide-settings-password-safe.html `Settings/Preferences | Appearance and Behavior | System Settings | Passwords` -- If it's a KeePass then you can **TRY** working with that file (I say try as it may still be encrypted with some master password etc). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs -- the file should be `c.kbdx`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot into recovery mode
2. Drop to root shell prompt
3. mount -rw -o remount /
4. ls /home
5. passwd root
6. enter new password
7. exit